# How to make a CREATE view & controller method for a model that has a list field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have these 2 models:

```
public class Invoice 
{
   public string InvoiceID {get; set; }

   public List<InvoiceElement> InvoiceElements {get; set;}

   [...other fields...]
}


public class InvoiceElement
{
   public string InvoiceElementID {get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("Invoice")]
   public string InvoiceID { get; set; }
   public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }

   public string Item {get; set;}

   [...other fields...]
}
```

I am unable to make a CREATE view for new **Invoices** that lets me add **InvoiceElements**.

I want to have a "CurrentInvoiceElements" table where to dinamically add rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just trying to making it simple. You can use the name attribute (the attribute that asp.net uses for modal binding) and post a list along with other properties of the class. You can use javaScript to append new elements to your form. Using the above modals you've provided, I have written a simple example using simple jQuery functions.

Razor View:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="add_btn">Add Invoice Element</button>
@using (@Html.BeginForm("SaveInvoice", "Invoice", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <!--Other modal attributes inputs goes here -->
  <!--You can use normal html helper extensions -->
  <table id="element_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Element Id</td>
        <td>Item</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input name="invoice.InvoiceElements[0].Item" id="InvoiceElements[0].Item" /></td>
          <td><input name="invoice.InvoiceElements[0].InvoiceElementID" id="InvoiceElements[0].InvoiceElementID" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#add_btn").on('click', function (e) {
    var table = $("#element_table");
    var idx = $(table).find("tbody>tr").length;
    var htmlToAppend = `<tr>
                            <td><input name="invoice.InvoiceElements[${idx}].Item" id="InvoiceElements[${idx}].Item" /></td>
                            <td><input name="invoice.InvoiceElements[${idx}].InvoiceElementID" id="InvoiceElements[${idx}].InvoiceElementID" /></td>
                        </tr>`;
    $(table).find("tbody").append(htmlToAppend);
  });
</script>
```

Controller / Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveInvoice(Invoice invoice)
{
    /* your logic here */
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
       _invoiceBusiness.SaveInvoice(invoice);
    return View();
}
```

Please make sure the variable name in the parameter of the action method matches the name used in the name attribute of the input tag. i.e. `name = "invoice.***" public ActionResult SaveInvoice(Invoice invoice)`

Comment: I tried using your example but instead of adding a new line to the table, when `add_btn` is pressed nothing happens and when  **Submit** is pressed the page reloads.

Comment: Any error in browser console? Have you tried debugging? I had run and verified this code, working fine for me

Comment: There are no errors in the browser console. It just reloads the page without any new line in the table.

Comment: The add button should add new rows with new input fields. And submit button posts all data to controller. Drop your email here, I'll send you the sample project.

Comment: I managed to make it work. The problem was the button needing to be outside of the **BeginForm** .

Comment: Can you think of a way to perform data validation for the model **InvoiceElement** on each added row?

Comment: In my opinion, you should write your own validation on client-side that is called before submitting the form to server, a javascript function to iterate over all the rows and verify if the data is in expected format.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this solution: https://github.com/danludwig/BeginCollectionItem some years ago, and worked fine.

If I'm not mistaken, at the time I managed to do it using only the HTML Helper: *HtmlPrefixScopeExtensions*. Then just make sure the name you give on your View when you do Html.BeginCollectionItem("name") is exactly the same as your collection on your ViewModel.

That's for binding back to the controller.

With this, you can dynamically add rows using AJAX per example.

I hope it's clear enough. If you don't understand it I may make a Github repository with this.