# Update collection values in Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to update values from collection in ASP.NET Form.

My ViewModel:

```cs
public class FormVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OptionsVM> Options { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(FormVM form) { }
```

How to change values in Options? Now the controller always receive the "Name" but "Options" in always null???

Comment: Welcome on board. How are you sending the collection back to the controller?

Comment: I guess you are trying to do something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61850072/how-to-make-a-create-view-controller-method-for-a-model-that-has-a-list-field.

Comment: The form is:  <form asp-controller="Forms" asp-action="Edit" method="post">
and inside the form: @foreach (var option in Model.Options)
{
    and here is the dark magic
    dont know how to update values from the collection and send it on submit.
    For now is: <input asp-for="@option" class="form-control" />
    but not working
}

Comment: What does your OptionsVM class look like?

Comment: Contains only two properties: string Title and bool IsMarked

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop instead in your form like below:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Options.Count; i++)
{
    <input asp-for="Options[i].Title" class="form-control" />
}
```

For more details, check Expression names and Collections in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-input-tag-helper)